# A function having two different antiderivatives.

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to calculate $$\int_0^3(x-1)^2dx$$
I found the antiderivative as $\dfrac{(x-1)^3}{3}+C$ and the definite integral as $\dfrac{8}{3}$.
But the answer in the book was given as $3$. (Thomas' Calculus 11th Edition, Exercises 5.3 Q59)
Then, I tried to find the integral using this site--> https://www.integral-calculator.com/ .
There, **Manually Computed Antiderivative** was given as $\dfrac{\left(x-1\right)^3}{3}+C$ and **Antiderivative Computed by Maxima** was given as $\dfrac{x^3}{3}-x^2+x+C$.
Now, definite integral of first expression is $\dfrac{8}{3}$ as I got. But, definite integral of second expression is $3$.

So, which one is correct and why?

Comment: I think you wrote the integrand incorrectly. Your antiderivative is correct, but you did not compute the value of the integral correctly.

Comment: I think you may be mixing up $(x - 1)^2$ and $(x^2 - 1)$

Comment: @Deane Where did I commit a mistake?

Comment: @SouparnaPal $\,\dfrac{\left(x-1\right)^3}{3}\,$ and $\,\dfrac{x^3}{3}-x^2+x\,$ differ by a constant, so the definite integrals must match. If they don't, recheck your calculations.

Comment: While calculating the value of first integral it seems ypu considered the lower limit as $1$.

Comment: Oh thanks. It was a simple calculation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one gives $\frac {8-(-1)}3=3$. So  the answers match. The anti-derivatives are both correct.